# How can I map a property to a class instance in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I've got a class

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public IDateTimeProvider DateTimeProvider { get; }

    public MyEntity(IDateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider)
    {
        DateTimeProvider = dateTimeProvider;
    }

    protected MyEntity()
    {
    }
}
```

When I map this to the `DbContext`, I want it to ignore this column (as it's not a primitive type).  When it loads from the database, I want it to populate this column with an instance of `DateTimeProvider`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I want to say something like:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(x => DateTimeProvider)
    .Ignore()
    .OnLoadInject(new DateTimeProvider());
```

Comment: I think you are doing a design mistake... Entity should only have properties that map with DB Table

Comment: @OrcusZ: not really, do you have any evidence supporting this statement or it's just a subjective opinion?

Comment: @chris31389: Why don't you have a parameterless constructor that just sets the value?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Ignore work. For the Provider, the `IServiceCollection` can be retrieve using `BuildServiceProvider()`. But I think this is design mistake to have this kind directly in the entity

Comment: Even the incoming [2.1 entity constructor injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services) won't support that - *Support for injecting application services is being considered for a future release*

Comment: @WiktorZychla: While it is _technically possible_ to have other properties in an entity (ones that do not map to the DB table), it's simply not a _good approach_ to do so. It inherently violates SRP, among other concerns. Coding standards like SRP cannot be empirically proven or disproven; they are a _guideline_ for good development. Asking for evidence is not really relevant for guidelines.

Comment: @Flatter: SRP has nothing to do with properties that don't map to the database. The key responsibility of the entity is not its mapping to the database but the role it plays in your domain. If you follow DDD, you can have pretty rich entities where only *selected part* of your entity is *possibly* persisted in a db. What is disputable is having **services** exposed from your entities, this would possibly violate the SRP, however the question is not about DDD/SRP and principles but technically - how to avoid mapping a non-primitive property and still have it injected.

Comment: I'm a believer in DDD and i'm trying to address the issue of using and controlling DateTimes within the domain.  I want the domain entity to create internal objects and record when it created them.  I want to be able to control those dates for unit test purposes

Comment: Maybe this is a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to create a column in the database, you can use the `[NotMapped]` annotation on the property. More info:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: How would you populate the DateTimeProvider property when it is loaded from the database?

Comment: Can't you do that in the constructor?

Comment: I want to try and avoid newing up a service in the constructor so that I can use Dependency Injection